# OpenGL atomic counter equivalent in CUDA

Tags: cuda, glsl, atomic

I've just started trying some CUDA programming, coming from OpenGL/GLSL.

In OpenGL, atomic counters appear to be separate from main graphics memory an have next to zero overhead (unlike the significantly slower, but not exactly slow, atomic operations on image units or "bindless graphics" memory). They are limited in that there are a fixed number of them (~16k) and they can ONLY be read, incremented or decremented, which I guess has lower overhead.

Is there an equivalent interface to these extremely fast atomic counters in CUDA?

I want to write something like this:

```
if (some_condition)
{
    index = atomicIncrement(globalCounter);
    output[index] = myValue;
}
```

The same result could be accomplished with a radix sort or "histopyramid"-like compaction but atomic counters are just simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using atomicAdd()? I don't know about the OpenGL atomics but I'd imagine they're similar.

```
int atomicAdd(int* address, int val);
unsigned int atomicAdd(unsigned int* address,
                       unsigned int val);
unsigned long long int atomicAdd(unsigned long long int* address,
                                 unsigned long long int val);
float atomicAdd(float* address, float val);
```

Comment: These newish GLSL atomic counters are supposed to implemented in faster, dedicated hardware where available. My understanding is that on hardware which comes in red boxes, there are a small number of dedicated hardware counters for this in recent architectures, whereas in hardware which comes in green boxes, the implementation is just done in global memory with standard atomic add instructions

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of atomicAdd. It seems to be similar to [imageAtomicAdd](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_image_load_store.txt) and [atomicAdd](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/GL_NV_shader_buffer_store.txt). I was just wondering if there was some other faster atomic increment at global scope, which OpenGL provides with [atomic counters](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_atomic_counters.txt)

Comment: @talonmies yes I've experienced this, even with the same hardware. In late 2011 a driver change gave a jump from atomic counters being just as fast as atomic operations to the near-zero overhead I mentioned.